# How to avoid static context reference when I need to use a activity context?

Tags: android, static, android-context

After read this topic [avoiding memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) some doubts arouse.

If I need to use an activity context (example: inflate a view in a `PopupWindow` class to show a popup) how can I hold the context of actual activity to do it? If I need to avoid a static context reference the only way to do it is creating an attribute in my class? And all the other classes I'll need the actual activity context I need to do it?

update-

I want to use this actual activity context in many classes that don't inherited Context, like I use with the application Context in my Application class that has a static method called `getApplicationContext()` declared. This method follows the Singleton Design Pattern and works fine.

Comment: Is it possible for the Activity to create an instance of one of these classes, passing in itself as the Context?  If you share some code, it would help explain what you need.

Comment: I think it's not , because these classes aren't created directly, They are created passing trhough many classes according to the nodes in a xml object. I hope this code can do you understand my situation: http://pastebin.com/x3LcgF0f

Comment: So, what is triggering the HTTP request and processing of XML?  Is it a Service or a user initiated action from an Activity?

Comment: Its almost an user initiated action from an Activity. The user needs to click a button for I call the "doHttpPost" method. The difference is the button is created dynamically in a separated class, that isn't inherited Context, so, it doesn't have a valid context to use.

Comment: You really need to provide an example of the full workflow.  See this for some suggestions for how to do so: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Here you go [link](http://pastebin.com/LHjUSBUr). I hope you can help me with this. Let's pretend I have a lot of classes like this buttonCreator, and for each one I have to create differents views, but the final step is it, in my main activity I only need to attach a view to the masterLayout.

Answer (score 2):

Working from the code you linked in the comments, why not do this:

```
//my main activity
public class ExampleStaticReferenceActivity extends Activity {
        //...

    public void methodCalledWhenUserPressesButton(){
        LinearLayout masterLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.masterLayout);
        //now passing a reference to the current activity - elevine
        masterLayout.addView(ButtonCreator.createButton(this));
    }
}

//this class is in another package
public class ButtonCreator {
        //added a Context parameter - elevine
        public static Button createButton(Context context) {
                Button button;

                button = new Button(context);
                //... some configurations for button
                return button;
        }      

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer ! But unfurtonately it's not so simple. As I said before, this creation doesn't occurs directly like that, I put the code this way to simplify your understand. In fact, for this creation I will receive an xml file with SASConnection class, populate my classes with SASEnvelope class, and while I'm populanting this SASEnvelope I'm creating those views for each node in this xml file. So, in this way you put here I need to pass the context to SASConn, then to SASEnvelope, and finally to every class I created the views. I was trying to avoid this approach and get another solution.

Comment: It sounds like you need to re-think your architecture and simplify it.

Comment: Well, my question is simple. When you need to hold the current activity context in a class that doesn't inherited Context you always have to pass it for paramter to a method right ? And if you need it in other points in that class you need to create a private field for this context right ? I think I'll have to do it if I want to eliminate the static context reference.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  This is a better approach then using statics due to the way Android manages the lifecycle of your application.  However, from what you have described so far your approach sounds overly complex.  You should try and decouple the creation of your View from your Activity which uses it.  Maybe you can create reusable XML layouts that can be inflated and added to a larger view.  Maybe you need Fragments or something like ListView which is data driven.  Hopefully, this gives you some pointers in the right direction.

Comment: yes, I'll try to change these things, thanks a lot for you help, you're such a helpfull guy =]

Answer (score 0):

That will crash your Application since Your Activity will be killed by OS when it runs out of Resources thus Context will also be null.. And its meaningless to give A background Activities Instance when you want to show pop up in the Foreground Activity..  What the Blog says is avoid passing activity.this where even getApplicationContext() can do the job..

Comment: So, what I need to do ? I read about it and made a static context reference is not a good approach. Actually I'm trying to hold the activity context list in a static field of a static class. In another class that I called CustomPopupWindow I inflate a template in the actual Activity, this actual Activity is my last element at the static list.

Comment: @digulino .. just use activity.this .. because your popUp lives only until your Activity gets finished.. so the Activity reference is released.. so no memory leak...